# Delphi / Android- TabItem Icon doesn't appear in device

Tags: android, delphi

I'm trying to put icons in my TabItems following http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Tab_Components_to_Display_Pages_(iOS_and_Android). The icons appear on the emulator but when I run the app in my tablet android, the icons doesn't appear.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

[Tabitemcustom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QhiJ.png)

I had that problem too and i missed one thing on that tutorial. You have to put

```
Stylelookup=tabitemcustom
```

for the tabitem. You can verify that it is working when you can see it on design mode. The image shows you what i mean.